# XPath/XQuery Regular Expression replacing a String pattern

Tags: regex, oracle, xpath

I have following xml to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE PROCESS_PO_007 SYSTEM "003_process_po_007.dtd">
<!-- Oracle eXtensible Markup Language Gateway Server  -->
<PROCESS_PO_007>
  <CNTROLAREA>..
```

I want to replace any comments in input xml by single space. I want to replace any tag starting with  and the string in-between with a space e.g

`<!DOCTYPE PROCESS_PO_007 SYSTEM "003_process_po_007.dtd">` should be replaced by ' '
similarly 
`<!-- Oracle eXtensible Markup Language Gateway Server  -->` should be replace by ' '

I am using following replace function but not successful:

```
replace(tab.user_data.payload, '&lt;!.*?&gt;', ' ')
```

but this is not working.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use  `regexp_replace` instead of `replace,` if you want to make a use of regular expressions

```
select regexp_replace('<!-- Oracle ...  -->blub', '<!.*?>', ' ') from dual
```

Comment: Can this function 'regexp_replace' be used in XPATH/XQUERY and its only for SQL commands ?

Comment: Yes this works as the de-queue condition of oracle apps adapter (oracle soa 11g) <property name="DequeueCondition" value="extract(xmltype(regexp_replace(tab.user_data.payload, '&lt;!.*?&gt;', ' ')),'//PROCESS_PO_007/DATA